# Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.recordfactory error soapui 5.5

Tags: apache-poi, soapui

I have been using SOAPUI 4.6.4 for rest API testing(data read from excel) and i have the below jars placed in the bin folder. All the excel related classes work perfectly work fine.
However on installing SOAPUI version 5.5 and placing the same jars in bin/ext folder, i get error "Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.recordfactory"

1. ooxml-schemas-1.3
2. poi-3.17
3. poi-ooxml-3.17
4. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17
5. poi-scratchpad-3.8

question: is there any other dependency i need to place in the bin folder apart from the above ones? or the version of dependencies to be upgraded?

Comment: Don't mix Apache POI versions - you have a mix of 3.8 and 3.17

Comment: thanks for the response. removing the 3.8 version did not help.

Comment: Check if SoapUI bundles an older or newer version of Apache POI